# Teradata SQL moving sum

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a table of 2 columns which has daily sales by date. I need to calculate a column which sums sales for the last 365 days.

I think we could use SUM Over with ROW Preceeding option. However I am not sure of the syntax.

Please help.

```
    RPT_DT  sales          last_year_sales
  2/1/2015  150,876.00  
  .     
  .     
  .     
 1/29/2016  430,715.31  
 1/30/2016  407,864.88  
 1/31/2016  355,793.55  
 2/1/2016   331,142.13  SUM sales from 2/1/15 to 01/31/16
 2/2/2016   269,016.02  SUM sales from 2/2/15 to 02/01/16
 2/3/2016   295,007.69  SUM sales from 2/3/15 to 02/02/16
```

Comment: Are there any gaps in the dates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this. Adjust "preceding" cutoffs per your need.hope this helps.

```
    Select 
    rpt_dt,
    sales,
    SUM(sales) OVER (ORDER BY rpt_dt ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND  1 PRECEDING)
    FROM test
    GROUP BY 1,2
    ORDER BY 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax/functions may need to be different for Teradata, but the following SQL query might help:

```
SELECT 
    s.rpt_date
    ,s.sales
    ,SUM(s2.sales)

FROM dailySales s
JOIN dailySales s2 ON
    s2.rpt_date BETWEEN DATEADD(dd, s.rpt_date,-365) AND  DATEADD(dd,s.rpt_date,-1)

GROUP BY
    s.rpt_date
    ,s.sales
```

The query joins the dailySales table to itself (one to many), fetching all records from the previous 365 days.  We then sum them up. Note that `s.sales` is not summed as this value will be repeated for each record in `s2`. (You could use `AVERAGE` rather than putting it in the `GROUP BY`)

Comment: If the table is large, this probably won't be the most efficient query - using a window function will be much better.

Answer (score -2):

try this :

```
select sum(sales) as sales from table1 where `date` between 01/01/2015 and 31/12/2015;
```

Comment: This does not answer my question

Comment: if it does'nt answer your question then you must down vote to  it,,,ofcourse,,,i'm just trying to figure it out,,,thanks..

Comment: I did not down vote. I dont have enough reputation score to vote down. Somebody else did